# Beginner's Java - Help Needed Using Eclipse

Tags: java

I have been busting my brain for days trying to complete this Java project and for the life of me I cannot get it to run. Here is what I am supposed to do:

1. Write a program that calls each of the methods of the Math class from the list below and provides output showing the method called, values sent to the method, and the returned results. Each listed method will tell you which values to use. For example:

   Listed method: `double pow(double a, double b):` use `2.0` and `3.0`. Your program would display: `Math.pow(2.0, 3.0) = 8.0`. When calling a method that accepts doubles, use numbers with at least one decimal digit like the example above, even if it's a zero. Remember that numbers with decimals are double literals. Try to use values that will produce easily verifiable results.

   Here is the list:

   ```
   double pow(double a, double b): Use 3.0 and 2.0
   double sqrt(double x): Use 25.0
   int max(int a, int b): Use 6 and 2
   double max(double a, double b): Use -50.0 and 7.0
   static double random()
   ```

   Sample output:

   ```
   Math.pow(3.0, 2.0) = 9.0
   Math.sqrt(25.0)=5.0
   Math.max(6,2)=6
   Math.max(-50.0,7.0)=7.0
   Math.random()= -random value-
   ```

---

2. Test your program with the values shown in the examples, fix any errors.
3. Add a method to your program called randomStudy that has no parameters and returns no value. In this method, do the following:

   a. Declare three int variables: total, min, and max. Set total to 0, min to 11, andmax to -1.

   b. Create a loop that will run 1,000 times. In the body of the loop, generate a random int value between 1 and 10, inclusive. Add this number to your total. If this number is less than min, update min with the new number. If it is greater than max, update max with the new number.

   c. After the loop, display the following:

   ```
   Min value: x
   Max value: y
   Average: z
   ```

   Replace x and y with your min and max values. Calculate z by dividing your total by 1000d.
4. Call your new randomStudy method from the main method.
5. Highlight and copy the output shown in Eclipse. Paste the output at the bottom of your source code file. Add the text Results:above your output, and then comment out the text your just dded plus the output text. Your commented results should look something like this:

   ```
   /*
   Results:
   Math.pow(3.0, 2.0)= 9.0
   Math.sqrt(25.0) = 5.0
   Math.max(6, 2) = 6
   Math.max(-50.0, 7.0) = 7.0
   Math.random() = -random number-
   Min value: 1
   Max value: 10
   Average: 5.553
   */
   ```

---

```
public class Method {

    public void main(String[] args) { 

public static double pow(double 3.0, double 2.0);
    public static double sqrt(double 25);
    public static int max(int 6, int 2);
    public static double max(double -50, double 7)
    public static double random()
    }
}

public class randomStudy{

   public void main(String[] args) {
       int min = 11;
               int max = -1;
               int total = 0;
    int i;
       for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
           int randomInt = (int)(11.0 * Math.random());
              System.out.println("Random integer between 1 and 10 : " + randomInt );
              int newtotal = (randomInt + int total);
              if int newtotal < int min {
                  int min = Math.random());
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("int min");
              }
              if int newtotal > max {
                  int max = Math.random());
              }
              else{
                  System.out.println("int max");
              }
         }
       System.out.println("Min value:" + int min);
       System.out.println("Max Value:" + int max);
       System.out.println("Average:"+ int newtotal / 1000d);
   }
}
```

I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method pow(double, double) is undefined for the type Math
    The method pow(double, double) is undefined for the type Math
    at Math.main(Math.java:3)
```

Comment: this is an outright off-topic, totally ignoring what Programmers is **[about](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/tour)**: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773

Comment: I recommend you read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I suggest you read the second and third chapter of the text book. You are not really on track.

Comment: Did you perhaps named one of your classes `Math`?

Comment: I think what you're missing is that there is an existing library in Java called Math that has the methods you need, like this:   System.out.println(Math.pow(2,3));

Comment: @TheJoeIaut Whether or not that's true, there's no need to be rude.

Comment: Error you posted has nothing to do with code from your question. Also judging by your code it looks like you have no idea abut what `static` means. Maybe before going any farther consider taking few steps back and reading book/tutorial (I liked "Thinking in Java" but from what I heard "Head-first: Java" is also good one).

Comment: You created a class called `Math`. Delete it. You are only supposed to write one class with a `main` method, and lots of prints of titles, and of results of calling `Math.pow(...)`, `Math.sqrt(...)` etc. And `randomStudy()` should be a method. Try again.

Comment: You do you not seem to have a firm grasp on how to structure or correctly write your code. Please see my answer below for an example of how it should be written. I used the code you have provided.

Comment: The error occurs in code you haven't posted (line 3 of Math.java). We therefore can not help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is structured incorrectly. You have multiple main methods which is a big problem. There should be only one for this program in particular. You are declaring variables that already exist:

```
int variableA = 0;
int variableA; // Overrides old variableA thus resetting the value
```

Instead you should be doing this to use the variable:

```
int variableA = 0;
variableA = 10;
```

You are also declaring methods in the main method which you cannot do. This is also the cause of your error.

```
public static double pow(double 3.0, double 2.0);
public static double sqrt(double 25);
public static int max(int 6, int 2);
public static double max(double -50, double 7)
public static double random()
```

You also cannot write 'double 3.0' when you declare a data type such as 'double' the next thing you write is the variable name, not a value. Please brush up on both Java and Programming basics before attempting to continue.

Below you will find your code fixed and reformatted. However I am not doing your work for you so you will have to figure out how to finish it yourself and learn by example.

In **'Math.java'**:

```
public class Math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Program starts here

        // Show and calculate math results here
        System.out.println("Math.pow(3.0, 2.0) = " + Math.pow(3.0, 2.0));
        // ...

        // This will execute the randomStudy method.
        randomStudy();
    }

    public void randomStudy() {
        // randomStudy method code goes here
        int min = 11;
        int max = -1;
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            int randomInt = (int)(11.0 * Math.random());

            System.out.println("Random integer between 1 and 10: " + randomInt);

            int newtotal = (randomInt + total);

            if (newtotal < min) {
                min = Math.random());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Min: " + min);
            }

            if (newtotal > max) {
                max = Math.random());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Max: " + max);
            }
         }

         System.out.println("Min value:" + min);
         System.out.println("Max Value:" + max);
         System.out.println("Average:"+ newtotal / 1000d);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great, I managed to figure this out on my own, and when I checked back I found this, so I think of it as a confirmation that I did in fact figure it out. Thank you for this!

Comment: Also when you did: "public void randomStudy()" I needed to change it to: "public static void randomStudy()" or else it would not execute the randomStudy in the main method.